# Error: Deployment of application to device failed. Error 0x80070005: Access is denied

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

At the first deploy the app is installed on my device and everything works well, but when I try to deploy the second time I get this error:

```
1>Deployment of application to device failed.
1>Error writing file '%FOLDERID_APPID_INSTALL%\{5ea233c7-23db-4a36-b02b-2554d58aba56}\resources.pri'. Error 0x80070005: Access is denied.
1> 
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried to look after this issue, but I can't find the solution for my problem with that "resources.pri".
Someone know how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Look at permissions on FOLDERID_APPID_INSTALL, it's definitely a permissions issue. Try the tool ProcMon for further investigation

Comment: Where I can find FOLDERID_APPID_INSTALL and what is that resources.pri? @JeremyThompson

Comment: Run ProcMon during the deploy and work out which directory it points to, you should also be able to search through build scripts, environment variables, etc to find out

Comment: I can't find anything with ProcMon.

Comment: Uninstall the app from the device and then try again.

Comment: Whenever I uninstall the app at the second deployment appear the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this issue too. Windows Phone 8.0 application, has been working well for several years, has 30,000 users, and all I want to do is update some text. The app will deploy successfully to an HTC 8x running Windows Phone 8.1, but has the above error when deploying to a Lumia 950 running Windows 10 Mobile.

This is not a bug in the app. [And ProcMon is no use or relevance, because this is a problem of deploying to a Windows Phone, thanks for replying without reading the question]

This is a bug in Windows 10 Mobile working with Visual Studio. It needs fixing.